# Performance difference between Linux and Windows when using Python Process

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing

I’m trying to speed up some code that should run fast in both Linux and Windows. However, the same code run in a Fedora 25 takes 131 seconds, while in a Windows 7 only 90 seconds (both computers with 8Gb of RAM and i7 and i5 processor, respectively). I’m using Python 3.5 in Fedora and 3.6 in Windows.

The code is the following:

```
nprocs = cpu_count()
chunksize = ceil(nrFrames / nprocs)
queue = Queue()
jobs = []

for i in range(nprocs):
    start = chunksize * i
    if i == nprocs - 1:
        end = nrFrames
    else:
        end = chunksize * (i + 1)
    trjCoordsProcess = DAH_Coords[start:end]
    p = Process(target=is_hbond, args=(queue, trjCoordsProcess, distCutOff, 
                angleCutOff, AList, DList, HList))
    jobs.append(p)

HbondFreqMatrix = queue.get()
for k in range(nprocs-1):
    HbondFreqMatrix = np.add(HbondFreqMatrix, queue.get())

for proc in jobs:
    proc.join()


def is_hbond(queue, processCoords, distCutOff, angleCutOff, 
             possibleAPosList, donorsList, HCovBoundPosList):

    for frame in range(len(processCoords)):
        # do stuff

    queue.put(HbondProcessFreqMatrix)
```

The start method of each process is actually considerably faster in Linux than in Windows. However, each iteration inside the is_hbond function takes 2.5 times longer in Linux (0.5 vs 0.2s).

The profiler gives the following information:

## Windows

```
Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.167    0.167   84.139   84.139  calculateHbonds
    4    0.000    0.000   52.039   13.010  \Python36\lib\multiprocessing\ queues.py:91(get)
    4    0.000    0.000   51.928   12.982   \Python36\lib\multiprocessing\ connection.py:208(recv_bytes)
    4    0.018    0.004   51.928   12.982   \Python36\lib\multiprocessing\ connection.py:294(_recv_bytes)
    4   51.713   12.928   51.713   12.928   {built-in method _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects}
    4    0.000    0.000   30.811    7.703   \Python36\lib\multiprocessing\ process.py:95(start)
    4    0.000    0.000   30.811    7.703   \Python36\lib\multiprocessing\ context.py:221(_Popen)
    4    0.000    0.000   30.811    7.703   \Python36\lib\multiprocessing\ context.py:319(_Popen)
    4    0.000    0.000   30.809    7.702   popen_spawn_win32.py:32(__init__)
    8    1.958    0.245   30.804    3.851   \Python36\lib\multiprocessing\ reduction.py:58(dump)
    8   28.846    3.606   28.846    3.606   {method 'dump' of '_pickle.Pickler' objects}
```

## Linux

```
Ordered by: cumulative time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.203    0.203  123.169  123.169  calculateHbonds
    4    0.000    0.000  121.450   30.362  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ queues.py:91(get)
    4    0.000    0.000  121.300   30.325  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ connection.py:208(recv_bytes)
    4    0.019    0.005  121.300   30.325  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ connection.py:406(_recv_bytes)
    8    0.000    0.000  121.281   15.160  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ connection.py:374(_recv)
    8  121.088   15.136  121.088   15.136  {built-in method posix.read}

    1    0.000    0.000    0.082    0.082  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ context.py:98(Queue)
 17/4    0.000    0.000    0.082    0.021  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>: 939(_find_and_load_unlocked)
 16/4    0.000    0.000    0.082    0.020  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>: 659(_load_unlocked)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.013  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ process.py:95(start)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.013  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ context.py:210(_Popen)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.052    0.013  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ context.py:264(_Popen)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.051    0.013  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ popen_fork.py:16(__init__)
    4    0.000    0.000    0.051    0.013  /python3.5/multiprocessing/ popen_fork.py:64(_launch)
    4    0.050    0.013    0.050    0.013 {built-in method posix.fork}
```

Is there a reason why this might be the case? I know the multiprocessing module works differently in Linux and Windows due to the lack of os.fork in Windows, but I thought Linux should be faster. 
Any ideas on how to make it faster in Linux?
Thank you!